# finding min odd number and max even number in a sequence

Tags: c++

I am trying this very simple problem:

Input:

Contains an integer number n (n ≤ 10^6) - the amount of elements in sequence, after it ai  (1<=i<=n) - elements in sequence

Output:

Write the minimal odd number and the maximal even number of the sequence. If there isn't such number then write "-1" instead of this number.

Input format:

5

1 2 3 4 5

Output: 1 4

What I tried is this, but still can't pass the online judge.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n, a, min, max;
    cin >> n;
    min = INT16_MAX; max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a >= max && a % 2 == 0) { max = a; }
        if (a <= min && a % 2 != 0) { min = a; }
    }

    if (min == INT16_MAX && min != 1) { min = -1; }
    if (max == 0) { max = -1; }
    cout << min << " " << max;
    return 0;
}
```

For a better understanding of what is wanted, if the input:

5

2 4 2 5 4

the output should be: -1 4 or 5 4?

Comment: Why not add the values into an array and sort it  and then the first odd number and (starting from the end) last even number are the answer

Comment: @auburg, you can't do sorting, you can't also do arrays. only loops and if conditionals.

Comment: Why did you init `min` by `n`?

Comment: @P. Dmitry, because a at most would be n.

Comment: Yes. But if you found `n` in sequence, you can't detect it, because you check `min == n`. The same story with `max`

Comment: Also, `else { min = min; }` do nothing, you can just remove it. Same for `max`

Answer (score 1):

The posted code, to find the maximum even number, follows this steps

```
int max = 0;
// ...
{
    // ...
    if (a >= max && a % 2 == 0) { max = a; }
}

if (max == 0) { max = -1; }
```

The quoted problem, though, doesn't seem to specify the range of the input values. So this would give to wrong result for every even value less than zero.

A similar issue is present in the logic used to find the minimum, which assumes that all the odd values are less than or equal to `INT16_MIN`.

---

> if the input (...) 2 4 2 5 4 
>   the output should be: -1 4 or 5 4?

To my understanding of the quoted problem, the output should be 5 4.
It would be -1 4 if the numbers were, e.g. 2 4 2 6 4 (no odd numbers).

---

To ensure that the found extremes are valid, you can use a couple of sentinel values, that is a values that can't possible be a (minimum) odd number and one that can't be a (maximum) even number:

```
const int odd_sentinel = 0;     // It isn't odd...
const int even_sentinel = -1;   // It's not even
int min_odd = odd_sentinel;
int max_even = even_sentinel;

int x;
while ( std::cin >> x )
{
    if ( x % 2 )
    {
        if ( min_odd == odd_sentinel  ||  x < min_odd )
            min_odd = x;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( max_even == even_sentinel  ||  x > max_even )
            max_even = x;
    }
}

std::cout << (min_odd == odd_sentinel ? -1 : min_odd) << ' '
          << (max_even == even_sentinel ? -1 : max_even) << '\n';
```

Comment: 1 <= i <= n, not ai, ai is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

`min` and `max` should be inited by values, that can't be in sequence, otherwise, you can't detect, did you find this value or it just didn't change since init.

Comment: e.g. try `min = n+1`

Comment: @JohnIlacqua, I did it before you mentioned it though.

Comment: No, still can t pass the online jydge

Comment: @P.Dmitry what do you think the problem might be? it still can not pass the judge. I tried a lot of test cases. Maybe the problem wants the literal min, max, just max to be even, and min to be odd, that is; if you have 2 2 5 4, the output should be: -1 4 rather than 5 4, do you think this interpret ion is correct.

Comment: @V_head Wait a minute. Why did you thought that ai <= n?

Comment: What is limitation for ai? If `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() <= ai <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` you can init `min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`

Comment: because it can't bigger than it as stated in the problem statement.

Comment: @V_head Can you provide the full text of the problem? In your question nothing about this limitation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200304/discussion-between-p-dmitry-and-v-head).

Answer (score 0):

Task description suggest the use of a fixed size array (106 elements) where **min** and **max** are the indexes to the minimal odd number and the maximal even number as there's nothing said about the values of the numbers (they could be all negative or even -1, so there's no safe initial value for min and max).

If you do not want to keep a copy of all numbers, then you can use two bool variables as flags to mark if min/max values have been initialized:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
  int n, a, min, max;
  cin >> n;
  min = -1; max = -1;
  bool minInit = false;
  bool maxInit = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> a;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      if (!maxInit || a > max) {
        maxInit = true;
        max = a;
      }
    } else {
      if (!minInit || a < min) {
        minInit = true;
        min = a;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << min << " " << max;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just In Case Anyone still Looking For A Generic Answer..

```
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A) {
int n = A.size();
int val1 = INT_MIN, val2 = INT_MAX;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (A[i] % 2 == 0) {
    val1 = max(val1, A[i]);
    } else {
    val2 = min(val2, A[i]);
    }
}
assert(val1 != INT_MIN);
assert(val2 != INT_MAX);
return val1 - val2;
```

}

val1 is maximum of Even & val2 is Minimum of Odd Number in An Array.